# Spellcheck Entire File in Vim

Tags: vim, vi, spell-checking, spelling

I am currently using Vim's spell checking and it is great, however when pounding out a long letter or some notes I often find it easier to ignore spelling errors and come back later.  However, mashing `[z` and then changing the word is a little annoying.  I was wondering if there is some sort of *wizard* approach that could be used (like `aspell check`) that would go through all the misspelled words in the document and provide the option to fix/add/ignore them.

Answer (score 5):

My [SpellCheck plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3844) shows all spelling errors as a quickfix list via `:SpellCheck`. You can then use the built-in quickfix navigation (e.g. `:cnext`, maybe bound to a key mapping) to quickly go through the list. Commands like `zg`, `z=` etc. are forwarded to the target spell error.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to map the spelling check key mappings to your numpad. It allows you to spell check the document quickly.

The keys I most often use are probably:

- next misspelled word -> numpad 3
- show alternatives ->numpad 5
- choose alternative -> 5 (and then enter number of selection to change
  the word)
- include the word in the dictionary -> numpad 8

It looks like this in my vimrc:

```
"------------------------------------
" Spell Check Key bindings
"------------------------------------  
nmap <silent> <F7> :call ToggleSpell()<CR>
nmap <k5> z=
nmap <k1> [s
nmap <k3> ]s
nmap <k8> zg
nmap <k9> zug
```

I'm used to it, and it is pretty fast, as you have all the spell-checking commands under one hand. And [ToggleSpell](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_spellcheck_with_function_keys) allows me to turn on the spell check after I'm done with the draft, and choose the language I need for the final edit.

Comment: Cool idea.  However I am on a laptop and am already key-limited.  It would be nice to have one key changes (`g`, `=`, ...).  +1 for a useful answer anyway :D